# Why shouldn't the [language-lawyer] discussion be migrated here?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142058/is-language-lawyer-really-an-effective-characterization-or-a-borderline-meta) on MSE asking to move it here (since it is only relevant to SO).

> declined - The edits are super minor. If you think this bears new discussion, re-ask the question on MSO and reference this post.

What edits? What new discussion? I was asking for a migration. Apparently, people agree with me since it is closed as "pertains only to a specific site".

Comment: Not everything that is site-specific should be migrated. The SE staff doesn't want *resolved* or *out-of date* discussions here.

Comment: Just because people closed it doesn't mean they agree with you that it should be migrated. They just agree it should be closed.

Comment: So what should be migrated?

Comment: As an aside, when I see resolved stuff being closed for being "site specific" I tend to close with the MSE specific "can no longer be reproduced" reason, which is (I think) more honest.

Comment: Still, tag-links in that Q&A will stay broken while it stays on MSE, and it is more difficult to refer to it there. There are many cross-references, and sometimes the discussion around a question is still valuable after the question is resolved, even if only to the original site... Also, migrating our stuff back here makes searching here more useful in general...

Comment: Frankly it's plain silly to close it for belonging on MSO instead of MSE and then not migrate it to MSO.

Comment: Related - [What should we do about Stack Overflow-specific questions on Meta SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231207)

Comment: @animuson, but *why* did they close it? Because it only pertained to a specific site (STACK OVERFLOW). Is the preferable thing for someone else to open the same question on MSO, rather than migrate it?

Comment: @Paul So what? We also have an off-topic reason for Super User that doesn't migrate things. It's an answered question that hasn't had any real activity in 2 years. Unless there's a *very compelling* reason to bring it here, simply closing it as off-topic is suitable. We don't need to migrate every question that only pertains to Stack Overflow to this Meta.

Comment: Eh, my 2p: It belongs here, not on Meta.SE.

Comment: @animuson If you don't care about old questions you may as well delete them.